# Is it possible to only store messages for 30 days in iCloud?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

My iPhone, iPad, and MacBook all have the Keep Messages setting on 30 days. When I turn on iCloud for Messages though, it changes to Forever and my iCloud storage fills up (I only have 5 GB). I can change it back to 30 days for each device, but the space Messages takes on iCloud remains the same (2.26 GB).

All my devices are using the latest version of iOS and macOS.

Is there a way to only store messages for 30 days in iCloud?

Comment: Are you sure the sync is finishing if your storage is filling up? It certainly won't start deleting local stuff until it's sure everything is uploaded.

Comment: @EzekielElin I don't think it finished syncing, but I was wondering if there is a way to change how long messages in iCloud stay for.

Comment: As far as I know, they must be manually deleted.